# Can't connect to local MySQL server - innodb error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, port

I was working on a project and I stored the data in a MySQL database. After updating windows 10, I couldn't connect to MySQL anymore. Could be an error in the port, but I'm not sure. Here's the error

```
2015-12-14 10:21:31 1eb0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 26731076
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
151214 10:21:31 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
151214 10:21:32 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
151214 10:21:32 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 26731086
151214 10:21:35 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
151214 10:21:35 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
151214 10:21:35 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 26731086
151214 10:21:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
151214 10:21:35 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

[image]

This is what I get as error on the screen:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\beyond 2045\php\connect.php on line 2
>   Database Connection FailedNo connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: Welcome to SO on this website we help people that are having problem with their code. Unless you post what you are using to connect to the MySQL server(for example if you are using code post the code). And what you already tried to solve this problem(So we can rule out those possibilities and help you better). We can not help you. So if you would update the question with those 2 things I mentioned we can help you better. Look here if you want to find out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to ask another question in the future.

Comment: There is not a single error in the log you posted, only notes and a warning. What's the error you get in PHP?

Comment: @BRoebie can you come up with some additional solution that I can try?

Comment: Can you show how your connection string is. In your code it seems to me that there is the problem

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I meant the error. Sorry:P it seems that there is something wrong with the connection string

Comment: @BRoebie It was working till the update. I think there's no problem with my code, but some system problem. Here's the connection code: <?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$db = mysql_select_db('2045');
if (!$db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

?>

Comment: check if the port number in the config of MySQL is 3306. **Note** Don't use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and in the newly released PHP 7.0 deleted. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead also take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to get an idea how to prevent SQL injections

Comment: @BRoebie Yes, the port is 3306. I tried to change it in 3307/8 but no difference. The reason I don't use mysqli is because I'm not used to, but I can try and see if I will be able to connect.

Comment: @BRoebie The problem is that I can't even start MySQL server from XAMPP. My code was working fine when I was able to connect